# Credentials in pip.conf for private PyPI

Tags: python, pip, config, pypi

I have a private PyPI repository. Is there any way to store credentials in `pip.conf` similar to `.pypirc`?

What I mean. Currently in `.pypirc` you can have such configuration:

```
[distutils]
index-servers = custom

[custom]
repository: https://pypi.example.com
username: johndoe
password: changeme
```

From what I've found that you can put in `pip.conf`:

```
[global]
index = https://username:password@pypi.example.com/pypi
index-url = https://username:password@pypi.example.com/simple
cert = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

But here I see two problems:

1. For each url you'll need each time to specify the same username and password.
2. Username and password become visible in the logs, cause they are part of the url.

Is there any way to store username and password outside of url?

Comment: I wonder if pip can work with ssh connection and use ssh keys for authentication. SSL certificates could be used to authenticate users as well, but of course for this you would need to change how the http server handles requests.

Comment: for 2. you could suppress stdout logging `pip install -q package-name` and if you still wanted the full verbose logs somewhere you could add the `--log` option as well to point to a file

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You could store credentials for Pip to use in `~/.netrc` like this:

```
machine pypi.example.com
    login johndoe
    password changeme
```

Pip will use these credentials when accessing `https://pypi.example.com` but won't log them. You must specify the index server separately (such as in `pip.conf` as in the question).

Note that `~/.netrc` must be owned by the user `pip` executes as. It must not be readable by any other user, either. An invalid file is silently ignored. You can ensure the permissions are correct like this:

```sh
chown $USER ~/.netrc
chmod 0600 ~/.netrc
```

This permissions check doesn't apply before Python 3.4, but it's a good idea in any case.

Internally Pip uses [requests](http://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) when making HTTP requests. requests uses the standard library [netrc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/netrc.html) module to read the file, so the character set is limited to an ASCII subset.

Comment: Thanks! That works. Strange, that `pip` itself doesn't have such functionality if it relies on `requests`.

Comment: This is great! One important distinction between using `.netrc` and `pip.conf` is that in `.netrc` a password with special characters MUST NOT be URL encoded, whereas in `pip.conf` it is required.

Comment: As an added comment, for those who wonder, this solution works on both linux and windows.

Comment: Hi @twm I try your solution but pip keep ignoring the configured password. I asked a new question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65926604/use-netrc-with-pip-and-gitlab-pypi).

Comment: Unfortunately this is not ideal if your Pypi repository is not hosted on its own domain. For example Gitlab’s Pypi repos use the domain `gitlab.com` and so you can have different repositories with different credentials on that same domain.

Comment: This causes conflicts with AzureDevops git lfs authentication

Answer (score 18):

How about storing the Username/Password as environment variables,

```
export username=username
export password=password
```

and referring to them in the pip.conf like so:

```
[global]
index = https://$username:$password@pypi.example.com/pypi
index-url = https://$username:$password@pypi.example.com/simple
cert = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

I use Gitlab CI's secret variables for storing credentials. Check for an equivalent in your CI tool.

Comment: For the 2nd part @MarkAWard's suggestion seems to do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Actually I was initially doing as you've suggested. I also use GitLab CI and I store username and password as the environment variables. The problem was, that `pip install` displays username and password in the output logs. But here suggestion from @MarkAWard helped. Currently only one question left, do you know if there is a way to forbid `echo $username` and `echo $password` output in GtiLab CI?

Comment: @KetanVatsalya Inside the pip.conf file, I had to wrap the environment variables inside curly braces else the environment variables won't be resolved. so `index = https://$username:$password@pypi.example.com/pypi` should be index = `https://${username}:${password}@pypi.example.com/pypi`

Comment: @rahul what version of pip are you using. I cant get the environment variables to resolve within pip.conf using both the curly braces and without curly braces option

Comment: Was this resolved ? Even I am not able to get the variables resolved inside pip.conf . I am using version 8.0.2

Comment: wasn't able to get it working either. would be nice to have

Comment: As far as I can tell pip.conf does't expand environment variables, so you'll have to add an extra step in your CI script using e.g. envsubst https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html

Comment: "index-url = https://<username>:<password>@pypi.example.com/simple" do the trick

Answer (score 7):

Given [issue 4789](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4789) is still open, you can utilize the following approach in your requirements.txt:

```
--extra-index-url=https://${PYPI_USERNAME}:${PYPI_PASSWORD}@my.privatepypi.com
private-package==1.2.3
...
```

If you try to run `pip install -r requirements.txt` with those environment variables set, you will find that pip still asks for credentials. This is because pip does not interpolate the expression `${PYPI_USERNAME}` as one would expect, but rather url encodes it. Your username and password in this example is expressed as `https://%24%7BPYPI_USERNAME%7D:%24%7BPYPI_PASSWORD%7D@my.privatepypi.com`

The work around here, and I admit there should be a better approach, but we can run pip as a script:

```
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

From man:

```
 -m module-name
    Searches sys.path for the named module and runs the corresponding .py file as a script.
```

Comment: A couple of things I don't understand here - 1) your two commands differ in whether they use the `-r` flag, is that just an omission on the first one, or is it important?  2) `python3 -m pip` should be exactly equivalent to just `pip`, assuming the correct Python is invoked.  I'm not sure why it would have the effect you describe, do you understand what's going on?

Comment: Why is the behavior different when using a module versus "pip" script??

Answer (score 3):

I know it is not answering the question the way it was formulated, but one could also use `keyring` python module for pip authentication:

https://pypi.org/project/keyring/

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/authentication/#keyring-support%3E

Comment: I use `tox`, and because `tox.ini` does not support multi-line install commands, keyring was too much of a pain to use. `PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL` was the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can simply **run pip install** and pass url to private repo as argument like so (I'm using Artifactory but it doesn't matter):

**Artifactory example:**

```
pip install {lib_name} -U -i https://{user_name}:{token_to_prvate_repo}@artifactory.{company_name}.com/api/pypi/pypi/simple
```

**Github example:**

```
pip install git+https://${GITHUB_USER}:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/user/project.git@{version}
```

**Bitbucket example:**

```
pip install  git+https://${BITBUCKET_USER}:${BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD}@bitbucket.org/user/project.git@{version}'
```

Variables can be read from pipeline/keay vault or other secure solutions.