# Pip.conf file to use environment variable

Tags: pip

Is it possible to have an environment variable as a part of the index url in `pip.conf`?

I tried using `$` and `${}` but it does not resolve the variables

Comment: May be duplicated with [Credentials in pip.conf for private PyPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468951/credentials-in-pip-conf-for-private-pypi)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can [set environment variables for pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#environment-variables) to use instead of specifying them in `pip.conf` file.

Use `export PIP_DEFAULT_INDEX_URL='some_url.com'` to set them.

To list all config, use `pip config list`. They should be set.

But beware of [config precedence](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#config-precedence):

> `--host=foo` overrides `PIP_HOST=foo`
>
> `PIP_HOST=foo` overrides a config file with `[global] host = foo`
>
> A command specific section in the config file [] `host = bar` overrides the option with same name in the [global] config file section

Comment: You can also provide more than one, using space as delimiter.

Comment: New documentation link is: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/configuration/#environment-variables