# Use .netrc with pip and gitlab pypi

Tags: python, pip, gitlab, .netrc

We have a gitlab pypi repository and a package that can be installed with the following command

```
pip install mypackage \
    --extra-index-url https://__token__:z-u5aFNdakdlsN@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/12345678/packages/pypi/simple
```

I try to follow the following answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55978589/3063243) to setup the password in `~/.netrc`.

My `~/.netrc` file

```
machine gitlab.com
    login __token__
    password z-u5aFNdakdlsN
```

And try to install with

```
pip install mypackage \
    --extra-index-url https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/12345678/packages/pypi/simple
```

Still, pip continue to ask for login and password

Am I missing something ?

Comment: I am assuming that isn't your password, so keep in mind that passwords in `.netrc` file should not contain spaces, since the `.netrc` file is parsed against spaces, tabs and new-lines.

Comment: Thx @dejdej. There is non space / tabs /new-line in the password. I made sure that the fake password in the question has the same format as the real one.

Comment: Remove what's before '@' in your pip.conf index-url (including the @) `--extra-index-url https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/12345678/packages/pypi/simple`

Comment: @phi did you succeed to resolve this please?
Thanks a lot