# Python pip - ignored .netrc and pip.conf files

Tags: python, pip

I want to install packages with `pip` and not be asked for the credentials and not to store credentials in `pip.conf` file
This is something which is explained previously here [Credentials in pip.conf for private PyPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468951/credentials-in-pip-conf-for-private-pypi)

So the steps I did.
in **/home/jenkins** folder I create `.netrc` file:

```
machine https://artifactory.domain.dev
    login username1
    password password1
```

in **/home/jenkins** folder I create `pip.conf` file:

```
[global]
index-url = http://artifactory.domain.dev/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-remote/simple
```

I create a virtualenv and try to install package:

If I specify URL in the command I am prompted for credentials:

```
python -m pip install python-cards -v -i https://artifactory.domain.dev/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-remote/simple
User for artifactory.domain.dev:
```

If I do not specify `-i` property then I see everything is installed but from the pypi.org which I shouldn't do that in that way (because on customer servers we will not have access to internet).

```
 python -m pip install python-cards
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/
```

It seems like both of my files `.netrc` and `pip.conf` are being ignored.
Why? Did I set up something wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here where to place the pip.conf: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/#location

Probably you want to place it here: **/home/jenkins/.config/pip/pip.conf**

I do believe that the .netrc should be directly in the home directory, but check that this file is owned by the user  that is executing pip. Replace $USER with the correct user (`jenkins`?) if it is not the current user

```
chown $USER ~/.netrc 
chmod 0600
```

Comment: in this link it says it should be at /etc/
https://www.shellhacks.com/pip-install-from-private-pypi-repository/
on the link in the question they are mentioning different location... why is this so confusing? I will test your recommendation

Comment: The **/etc/pip.conf** should also work, then it is available system-wide. There are three options each with a different scope. Each of them is described in the link I posted. The suggestion I provided would only give the user jenkins access to this configuration.

Comment: Teije I do have some progress.
When I set them in the location which you mentioned - I see that now it does target my repo, that is good!

`pip install sample1001
Collecting sample1001
User for artifactory.domain.dev:`

Bad thing is that is still does not catch `.netrc` file. It seems like it has a bad location as well. If I set credentials in pip.conf file then it will work. But as I read it is much better to have those credentials within the .netrc file

Comment: Perhaps important to check if the **.netrc** file owned by the user that uses pip? following this related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468951/credentials-in-pip-conf-for-private-pypi?noredirect=1&lq=1


    chown $USER ~/.netrc
    chmod 0600 ~/.netrc

Comment: Thanks but I have already put that same link at the top of my question... I did `chmod` and `chown` commands. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://www.labkey.org/Documentation/wiki-page.view?name=netrc) description of `.netrc`:

Port Independence

Note that the netrc file only deals with connections at the machine level and should not include a port number or protocol designation (http:// or https://), meaning both "mymachine.domain.org:8888" and "https://mymachine.domain.org" are incorrect. Use only the part between the slashes and/or any colon:port.

If you see an error message similar to "Failed connect to mymachine.domain.org:443; Connection refused", remove the port number from your netrc machine definition.

So, in your case it should be:

```
machine artifactory.domain.dev
login username1
password password1
```

After that, run the command (it seems that you still need either `--index-url` or `--extra-index-url`):

```
pip install --extra-index-url=https://artifactory.domain.dev <package-name>
```

Or add `index-url` or `extra-index-url` to `pip.conf`:

```
[install]
extra-index-url = https://artifactory.domain.dev
```

By the way, I noticed error here "in /home/jenkins folder I create pip.conf file". `pip.conf` should be in `~/.pip/pip.conf` or in `~/.config/pip/pip.conf` by default.