# Azure DevOps: System Personal Access Token (PAT)

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps I created `Feed` containing a `Python Library`. According to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/python-packages?view=azure-devops) a Personal Access Token is required to access the library:

```
[global]
extra-index-url=https://<FEED_NAME>:<YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN>@pkgs.dev.azure.com/<ORGANIZATION_NAME>/_packaging/<FEED_NAME>/pypi/simple/
```

We want to use the library in a server which doesn't belong to a specific user. How can I create a user independent access token?

Making the library public is no option for me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We want to use the library in a server which doesn't belong to a specific user. How can I create a user independent access token?

**User independent access token** is NOT supported for the syntax in pip.ini (Windows) or pip.conf (Mac/Linux) file, if you use on local machine.

This is because when you would like to access the DevOps private feed, **the account must be listed in the feed setting -> permission page**, otherwise you cannot access the feed. It could be 3 types:

1. personal account or user group.
2. `Project Collection Build Service ({OrgName})` or `{Project Name} Build Service ({Org Name})` identity, which is used as scoped identity($(system.accesstoken)) in pipeline.
3. Service principal(wadeapp2 below)

[image]

Service principal doesn't point to specific user, however we cannot create the personal access token with it.

For the scoped identity, it's used in pipeline but not local machine.You can check my answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77415770/is-it-possible-to-use-a-json-web-token-jwt-in-a-pip-conf-file) for your reference.